# Can't deploy with capistrano from windows to centos

Tags: ruby, windows, deployment, capistrano

I have Windows 7 64bit. I installed ruby200-x64 with official installer. I could successfully deploy with Capistrano one time, but now this kind of error appears all the time:

```
[deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: user@77.77.77.77 (TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String)
```

The remote server is running CentOS and is configured ok, because I can deploy to it from Xubuntu and Mac OS without any problems.

The deploy file looks like this:

```
set :application, "application_name"
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:username/application_name.git"
set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/application_name/"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, [".git", ".DS_Store", ".gitignore", ".gitmodules"]

server "user@77.77.77.77", :app

namespace :application do
  task :symlink, :roles => :app do
    run "if [ -d #{shared_path}/uploads ]; then ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/wp-content/uploads; fi"
  end

  task :chmod_wp, :roles => :app do
    run "chmod -R 755 #{release_path}/.*"
    run "find #{release_path}/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \\;"
  end
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", "application:symlink", "application:chmod_wp"
```

Maybe someone has a slight idea what's the problem with deploying from Windows?

Comment: my first impression is that net-ssh might not be functioning properly on windows.  Can you post the complete capistrano log?

Comment: by capistrano log you mean all that gets outputted after I run cap deploy? the net-ssh version is 2.6.7 by the way